# How to bind bar series in telerik c# to my DataTable

Tags: c#, oracle, telerik

I am developing a dashboard application for my POS application using telerik framework, I have developed 2 dashboard controls using Cartesian Points (binding them to my datatable) now my problem is that I cannot not bind bar series to the datatable to generate bar chart in chartview. Here is the code i have used earlier to generate pie chart in chartview. this code worked perfectly for me:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string PurchaseQuery = "Select ProductQt as Qt , ProductName as Product From ProductTable";
                    dt = oa.GetDataTable(PurchaseQuery);
                    PieSeries series = new PieSeries();
                    series.ValueMember = "Qt";
                    series.DataSource = dt;
                    series.DisplayMember = "Product";
                    series.ShowLabels = true;
```

and here is my code for binding bar series:

```
BarSeries barSeries = new BarSeries("Exp_Amount", "Exp_Type");
            adapter = new OracleDataAdapter();
            OpenConnection();
            adapter.SelectCommand = new OracleCommand("Select Exp_Amount,Exp_Type From ExpensesTable", con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            barSeries.DataSource = dt;
            barSeries.DisplayMember = "Exp_Amount";
            barSeries.ValueMember = "Exp_Type";
            radChartView1.Series.Add(barSeries);
```

but unfortunately this code does not bind to datatable. can someone help me to sort this out?

Comment: no one here can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when I bind the chart to any series I use the reader and add a data point at every step so instead of using the DataSource property, I use:

```
barSeries.DataPoints.Add(new CategoricalDataPoint(expAmount,expType)); ( in a while loop)
```

Another thing that I notice different than Telerik's example is your order so you might want to try following the order in this example :

http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/chartview-databinding-binding-to-datatable.html